# Center Navbar css with position:fixed

Tags: css, navbar, center, sticky

I have a navbar that has position:fixed, but when I scroll down the page it isn't centered. The width is 90% and the height is automatic. I included what I have in now, but it isn't working. Any ideas?

```
.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  height:auto;
  top: 0;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


<script>
        
        window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

        
        var navbar = document.getElementById("navbar");

        
        var sticky = navbar.offsetTop;

        function myFunction() {
          if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
            navbar.classList.add("sticky")
          } else {
            navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
          }
        }
    </script>
```

here is the HTML used to create the navbar

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" style="background-color:#3A9DFA; width:80%">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"  style="color:#ffffcc">Music Moves</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="background-color:#3A9DFA; color:#ffffcc">Months<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="october20.html">October 2020</a></li>
            <li><a href="november20.html">November 2020</a></li>
            <li><a href="december20.html">December 2020</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#top"  style="color:#ffffcc">Top</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown active">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" style="background-color:#3A9DFA; color:#ffffcc">Song's from October<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
           <li><a href="#chandelier">Chandelier</a></li>
           <li><a href="#talkhouse">Talkhouse</a></li>
           <li><a href="#savagemode2">Savage Mode 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </ul>
        
        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="/action_page.php">
           <div class="form-group">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
           </div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi Can you post your HTML as well?

Comment: @John What part of the HTML? This is the java I used  for the navbar is updated in the post

Comment: The HTML for the entire navbar

Comment: @John I'm trying... this is my first post on stack overflow

Comment: Its no problem.  You can see I edited your post and put the code in properly.

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else, I really appreciate the help!

Comment: Ok.  What part of it is not working?

Comment: When I scroll down the page and engage the position:sticky css, the navbar is stuck to the left side and I want to center the entire navbar when the sticky is engaged

Comment: I'm not sure I have all the code I need to help you out.  Can you put everything you have into a https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=GBMq9L0icV I put in all of my CSS and HTML

Comment: I have posted an answer. Please look and I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove  `left: 0;` and `margin: 0;` from `#navbar` in CSS